# Cooked Meat vs Steak N' Mushrooms

Tags: how-to-survive

Both "Cooked Meat" and "Steak N' Mushrooms" fill hunger 100%. I've noticed that "Cooked Meat" also gives a bit of health, whereas the other gives very little if any health.

So what's the deal, why would I want to change my "Cooked Meat" into "Steak N' Mushrooms"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need it for a Monkeys mission.

Beside this, there is no advantage of adding mushrooms.
Same with Fish N'Chips.

[Steam Discussion.](http://steamcommunity.com/app/250400/discussions/0/540743212326329236/)

Seems like the Cooked Meat heals 20hp while Steak N'Mushrooms doesn't.